# How to create a correct association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Tell me how to build a relationship between the models as follows:
- You can have a lot of posts
- Other users can write to each other positions on the wall (as in social networks, namely, when you can itself create a record or you can create it on another user page.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least try to do it yourself, but here is solution:
User model:

```
User (id, name)
 has_many :posts
 has_many :comments
 has_many :commented_posts, through: :comments
```

Post model:

```
Post (id, content, user_id)
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :comments
```

Comment model:

```
Comment (id, content, post_id, user_id)
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :post
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refereing to posts as medium with which user can tag other users, so that the post can appear on their walls.

You can definetly use posts to write to other people walls. Thats how any social platform works, same post can act as standalone post like a blog user is publishing for his followers or in particular community.

I a social feed like platform, tags the users on the post is the only way to push the post on wall feed of any user.

So Here we can have the following entities.

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :usertags      
    has_many :posts         
end
```

Post

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :usertags, as: :usertagable
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments ,:as => :commentable 

end
```

Usertag

```
class Usertag < ApplicationRecord


    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :usertagable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

i have build polymorphic relations for usertags as you may extend the current schema to involves comments on the posts as well like the following comment model, which can be served using polymorphic relations.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  # all the relations for the comment 
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable 
    has_many :usertags, as: :usertagable  
end
```

Comment in turn belong to a users/author, post to which comment is attached, comment can also be commented so it can also belong to commentable. Also comment can have user mentioned as wells like posts can.

A social feed like platform, tags the users on the post is the only way to push the post on wall feed of any user.

Now you can easily fetch all the posts belonging to particular user along with usertagged, comments, auther of comments.

```
post_list = Post.eager_load(:followers, :user, :communities, :usertags => :user, :comments => [:usertags => :user]).select("*").where("user.id is ?", :user_id)
```

Hope this helps
Thanks.

Comment: i have edited my answer with more detailed info , on how you can use this to write on other users feed/wall. Hope it helps.